# Keeping a responsive UI while adding Grids to the UI in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, xamarin, grid

I've written a Xamarin App in C# that registers barcode scans. The picker gathers articles, scans them and put them into boxes for the customer.

In the app the picker has the possibility to view all articles per box. All he has to do is toggle a switch on the page. Dynamically a grid with articles is created per box and added to the UI. This loading takes a lot of time, it often times out or is not complete. I tried to make the UI more responsive by using async/await, Tasks and Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread. What I would like to see is that the boxes are faster loaded and displayed 1 by 1 on the UI instead of all at the end. Can anyone help me with this?

The XAML:

```
<ContentPage Title="Box" x:Name="cp2">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="20">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Spacing="0">
                <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="Boxnr:"/>
                <Entry x:Name="txtBoxNr" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="200" 
                       Text="{Binding CurrBoxNr}" FontSize="Small" IsEnabled="{Binding BoxNrEnabled}" Completed="txtBoxNr_Completed"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout x:Name="txtOverviewTitle" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0" Spacing="0" IsVisible="False">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Maroon">
                    <Label VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           Text="Scan overview" FontSize="22" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Switch x:Name="swOverview" VerticalOptions="Center" Toggled="swOverview_Toggled" IsToggled="False"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout x:Name="Loader" Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="false">
                    <Label x:Name="message1" Text="Loading overview. Please wait..." TextColor="Maroon" IsVisible="false"/>
                    <Label x:Name="message2" Text="Closing overview. Please wait..." TextColor="Maroon" IsVisible="false"/>
                    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="ailoader" Color="Maroon" IsRunning="false"/>
                </StackLayout>
                <Label x:Name="txtUsedBoxes" Margin="10,10,10,5" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="" IsVisible="false"/>
                <BoxView x:Name="bvLine" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Maroon" IsVisible="false"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <ScrollView x:Name="scrloverview">
                <StackLayout x:Name="Overview" Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="false"/>
            </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

XAML.cs:

```
private void swOverview_Toggled(object sender, ToggledEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Value == true)
                GetOverview();
            else
                RemoveOverview();
        }

private async void GetOverview()
        {           
            message1.IsVisible     = true;
            ailoader.IsRunning     = true;
            Loader.IsVisible       = true;

            #region 1. Clear all children under the StackLayout
            Overview.Children.Clear();           
            #endregion

            #region 2. Display the overview title and the used boxes (without box 0)
            IEnumerable<decimal> boxes = viewModel.Scanlist
                                                    .Where(c => c.Box > 0)
                                                    .OrderBy(c => c.Box)
                                                    .Select(c => c.Box).Distinct();
            string strboxes = "Used Boxes: ";
            for (int i = 0; i < boxes.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (boxes.ElementAt(i) > 0)
                {
                    strboxes += (boxes.ElementAt(i)).ToString("N0");
                    if (i < boxes.Count() - 1)
                        strboxes += ", ";
                }
            }
            txtUsedBoxes.Text = strboxes;
            #endregion

            #region 3. Insert the overview of the scanned articles per box
            foreach (decimal box in boxes)
            {
                await Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => AddGridBox(box));
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", exp.Message, "OK");
                    }
                });
            }
            #endregion

            #region 4. Insert the overview of the unscanned articles in box 0
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => AddGrid0());
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", exp.Message, "OK");
                }
            });

            Loader.IsVisible       = false;
            message1.IsVisible     = false;
            ailoader.IsRunning     = false;           
            #endregion
            
            txtUsedBoxes.IsVisible = true;
            bvLine.IsVisible       = true;
            Overview.IsVisible     = true;
        }

private async void RemoveOverview()
        {
            Loader.IsVisible       = true;
            message2.IsVisible     = true;
            ailoader.IsRunning     = true;
            Overview.IsVisible     = false;
            txtUsedBoxes.Text      = "";
            txtUsedBoxes.IsVisible = false;
            bvLine.IsVisible       = false;

            

            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {                       
                        Overview.Children.Clear();                                                                    
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", exp.Message, "OK");
                }
            });

            message2.IsVisible = false;            
            ailoader.IsRunning = false;
            Loader.IsVisible   = false;
        }

private void AddGrid0()
        {            
            IEnumerable<Scanning> selection0 = viewModel.Scanlist
                                                .Where(c => c.Box == 0)
                                                .OrderBy(c => c.Article);

            if (selection0 != null && selection0.Count() > 0)
            {
                decimal scanneditems0 = selection0.Sum(e => e.Scanned);
                decimal quantity0     = selection0.Sum(e => e.Quantity);
               
                Label boxnr0 = new Label
                {
                    Margin         = new Thickness(10, 10, 0, 0),
                    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                    Text           = "Unscanned articles : Quantity: " + quantity0.ToString("N0")
                };

                Grid grdbox0 = new Grid();
                AddHeaders(grdbox0, selection0.Count() + 2, true);
                AddContent(grdbox0, selection0, true);

                Overview.Children.Add(boxnr0);
                Overview.Children.Add(grdbox0);
            }
        }
private void AddGridBox(decimal box)
        {           
            IEnumerable<Scanning> selection = viewModel.Scanlist
                                                .Where(c => c.Box == box)
                                                .OrderBy(c => c.Article);

            decimal scanneditems = selection.Sum(e => e.Scanned);
            decimal quantity     = selection.Sum(e => e.Quantity);

            Label boxnr = new Label
            {
                Margin         = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0),
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                Text           = "Box " + box.ToString("N0") + ": Scanned: " + scanneditems.ToString("N0")
            };

            Grid grdbox = new Grid();
            AddHeaders(grdbox, selection.Count() + 2, false);
            AddContent(grdbox, selection, false);

            Overview.Children.Add(boxnr);
            Overview.Children.Add(grdbox);
        }
private void AddHeaders(Grid grid, int rowcount, bool notscanned)
        {
            #region 1. Set grid margins and spacing
            grid.Margin          = new Thickness(30, 0, 30, 20);
            grid.ColumnSpacing   = 10;
            grid.RowSpacing      = 0;
            grid.BackgroundColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond;
            #endregion

            #region 2. Set row & column definitions     
            //Row definitions
            RowDefinitionCollection rdrow = new RowDefinitionCollection();
            for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
            {
                RowDefinition rowdef = new RowDefinition();
                rowdef.Height = (i == 1 ? new GridLength(1) : new GridLength(20));  // GridLength.Auto;
                rdrow.Add(rowdef);
            }
            grid.RowDefinitions = rdrow;

            //Column definitions
            ColumnDefinitionCollection rdcol = new ColumnDefinitionCollection();
            AddColumnDefinition(rdcol, new GridLength(60));                         //location
            AddColumnDefinition(rdcol, new GridLength(70));                         //article
            AddColumnDefinition(rdcol, GridLength.Star);                            //description
            AddColumnDefinition(rdcol, new GridLength(35));                         //quantity

            if (!notscanned)
                AddColumnDefinition(rdcol, new GridLength(35));                     //scanned

            grid.ColumnDefinitions = rdcol;
            #endregion

            #region 3. Add grid header
            //Add the labels to the header
            AddHeaderLabelToGrid(grid, 0, 0, "Location", 12, TextAlignment.End, FontAttributes.Bold);
            AddHeaderLabelToGrid(grid, 1, 0, "Article", 12, TextAlignment.Start, FontAttributes.Bold);
            AddHeaderLabelToGrid(grid, 2, 0, "Description", 12, TextAlignment.Start, FontAttributes.Bold);

            if (!notscanned)
            {
                AddHeaderLabelToGrid(grid, 3, 0, "Qty", 12, TextAlignment.End, FontAttributes.Bold);
                AddHeaderLabelToGrid(grid, 4, 0, "Scn", 12, TextAlignment.End, FontAttributes.Bold, new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0));
            }
            else
                AddHeaderLabelToGrid(grid, 3, 0, "Qty", 12, TextAlignment.End, FontAttributes.Bold, new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0));

            //Add the line to the header
            BoxView bx = new BoxView
            {
                HeightRequest     = 1,
                Color             = Color.Black,
                VerticalOptions   = LayoutOptions.End,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };
            grid.Children.Add(bx, 0, 1);

            if (notscanned)
                Grid.SetColumnSpan((BindableObject)bx, 4);
            else
                Grid.SetColumnSpan((BindableObject)bx, 5);
            #endregion
        }
private void AddColumnDefinition(ColumnDefinitionCollection rdcol, GridLength width)
        {
            ColumnDefinition coldef = new ColumnDefinition();     
            coldef.Width = width;                              
            rdcol.Add(coldef);
        }
private void AddContent(Grid grid, IEnumerable<Scanning> selection, bool notscanned)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < selection.Count(); i++)
            {
                Scanning scn = selection.ElementAt(i);

                #region 2. Add the data to the different columns                
                AddLabelToGrid(grid, 0, i + 2, scn.Location, 12, TextAlignment.End, notscanned, Color.Black);
                AddLabelToGrid(grid, 1, i + 2, scn.Article, 12, TextAlignment.Start, notscanned, Color.Black);
                AddLabelToGrid(grid, 2, i + 2, scn.Description, 12, TextAlignment.Start, notscanned, Color.Black);

                if (!notscanned)
                {
                    AddLabelToGrid(grid, 3, i + 2, scn.Quantity.ToString("N0"), 12, TextAlignment.End, notscanned, Color.Black);
                    AddLabelToGrid(grid, 4, i + 2, scn.Scanned.ToString("N0"), 12, TextAlignment.End, notscanned, Color.Black, new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0));
                }
                else
                {                    
                    AddLabelToGrid(grid, 3, i + 2, scn.Quantity.ToString("N0"), 12, TextAlignment.End, notscanned, Color.Black, new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 0));
                }
                #endregion
            }
        }
private void AddHeaderLabelToGrid(Grid grid, int column, int row, string text, int fontsize, TextAlignment alignment, FontAttributes fontattributes, Thickness? margin = null)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label
            {
                Text                    = text,
                FontSize                = fontsize,
                FontAttributes          = fontattributes,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = alignment
            };
            if (margin != null)
                lbl.Margin = (Thickness)margin;

            grid.Children.Add(lbl, column, row);
        }
private void AddLabelToGrid(Grid grid, int column, int row, string text, int fontsize, TextAlignment alignment, bool notscanned, Color textcolor, Thickness? margin = null)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label
            {
                Text                    = text,
                FontSize                = fontsize,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = alignment
            };
            if (!notscanned)
                lbl.TextColor = textcolor;
            if (margin != null)
                lbl.Margin    = (Thickness)margin;

            grid.Children.Add(lbl, column, row);
        }
```

Scanlist = Collection of Scanning objects

```
private ObservableCollection<Scanning> _scanlist { get; set; }
        
public ObservableCollection<Scanning> Scanlist
{
     get
     {
         return _scanlist;
     }
     set
     {
         _scanlist = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Scanlist");
     }
}
```

The Model:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

/* *********************************************************************************************
 * Class: Scanning
 * ----------------------
 * These classes are used to hold the pickinglist data of this application.
 * Scanning is the Model in the MVVM and implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.
 ***********************************************************************************************/

namespace BarcodeScanning
{
    public class Scanning : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private decimal _scanned;
        //private decimal _bo;
        private decimal _box;
        private bool _showdelete;
        private bool _showedit = false;
        private bool _showchangebox;
        private bool _containsbo;
        private bool _showmanco;

        [JsonProperty("pickexped")]
        public string Pickexped { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("pickngn")]
        public decimal Pickngn { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("orderdoc")]
        public string Orderdoc { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("location")]
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("article")]
        public string Article { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ean")]
        public string EAN { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("scanned")]
        public decimal Scanned { 
            get { return _scanned; } 
            set
            {
                _scanned = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Scanned");
            } 
        }

        [JsonProperty("box")]
        public decimal Box {
            get { return _box; }
            set 
            {
                _box = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Box");
            } 
        }
        
        [JsonProperty("ster")]
        public string Ster { get; set; }
      
        public bool ShowEdit
        {
            get { return _showedit; }
            set
            {
                _showedit = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowEdit");
            }
        }

        public bool ShowDelete
        {
            get { return _showdelete; }
            set
            {
                _showdelete = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowDelete");
            }
        }

        public bool ShowChangeBox
        {
            get { return _showchangebox; }
            set
            {
                _showchangebox = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowChangeBox");
            }
        }

        public bool ShowManco
        {
            get { return _showmanco; }
            set
            {
                _showmanco = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShowManco");
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("containsbo")]
        public bool ContainsBo
        {
            get { return _containsbo; }
            set
            {
                _containsbo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ContainsBo");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `viewModel` ,  `viewModel.Scanlist` and function  `AddGridBox`? Could you please post more code snippets or a basic demo so that we can try to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I updated the code above with the other functions for the grid and the model. Scanlist is a collection of Scanning objects. The picker starts with his pickinglist and all items (sometimes up to 600-700 articles) reside in box 0 (= no box yet). When he scans the boxes and articles, for each box (=grid) the articles need to be displayed.

Comment: Could you please post the code of  `ViewModel`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Xamarin doesn't begin display update immediately, because it tries to optimize the case where several UI changes are made at once; it prefers to do a display update with all those changes together, to save time.

You can force a layout cycle:

```cs
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => 
{
    AddGrid0();
    // Overview is the x:Name of layout to which children are being added.
    Overview.ForceLayout();
});
```

CAVEAT: If you display the boxes one at a time, the total time taken will likely increase. Consider only forcing every 3rd box or so.